# code doesn't run, gives no error messages (java, new to programming)

Tags: java

I'm pretty much brand new to programming, working through a class online. I am trying to write code that will tell you if a number is a square. When I run this code, it just loads for a while and then says killed. Is there something wrong with it? Usually if theres something wrong there is an error message or something, this just gives me nothing.

```
class Number {

    int number;

    public boolean isSq() {

        int y = 1;
        int sqNum = y*y;

        while (sqNum < number) {

            y++;
        }

        if (sqNum == number) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }


    }

}

Number myNumber = new Number();
myNumber.number = 36;   

System.out.println(myNumber.isSq());
```

Comment: Well, first your code doesn't compile. You can't have statements outside of a class. Please correct that one first, put it inside class and method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (sqNum < number) { 
    y++; 
}
```

never ends. You need to change `sqNum` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should have included sqNum = y * y; inside the while after y++;
Check the below code

```
public class Number {
    int number;
    public boolean isSq() {
        int y = 1;
        int sqNum = y * y;
        while (sqNum < number) {
            y++;
            sqNum = y * y;
        }
        if (sqNum == number) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Number myNumber = new Number();
        myNumber.number = 8;
        System.out.println(myNumber.isSq());
    }

}
```

or you change your isSq() as follows

```
public boolean isSq() {
        int temp = (int) Math.sqrt(this.number);
        if (this.number == temp * temp){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```